# How do you get a value from a select tag using PHP in a form with multiple textboxes?

Tags: php, html

So this is my sample code, it takes an input from a select tag and a textbox. The problem is,most examples I see on google only use a single select tag within a form tag and posting the data to the php variable. I need to get both of these values to the query simultaneously. Should I use javascript instead to get the value of the select tag, or is there any way to do post both the data from the textbox and a select tag in a single form?

employee.php

```
     <form name = "AddEmployee"method="post" action ="php/employeetabsubmit.php" >      
            <input type="text" name="surname" id = "surname" placeholder="Surname Here">
            <select name="empStanding">
              <option value="ADMIN">ADMIN</option>
              <option value="EMPLOYEE">EMPLOYEE</option>
              <option value="SUPERVISOR">SUPERVISOR</option>

            </select> 
             <button class="add" type="submit" name="add">Add</button>
       </form>
```

employeetabsubmit.php

```
   <?php

    $conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','employee');
    if(!$conn){
    die('Could not Connect My Sql:' .mysql_error());
    }

    else{

        echo '<script>console.log("Connected to DATABASE")</script>';
    }


     if (isset($_POST['add'])){
      $surname_string = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['surname']);//sample input
      $employee_standing = $_POST['empStanding'];

      $sql="INSERT INTO employee_table (emp_surname, emp_standing) VALUES ('$surname_string','$employee_standing');


       if (!mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
          die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
        }
        echo "1 record added";

        mysqli_close($conn);
     }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add enctype="multipart/form-data" in form attribute.

```
   <form name = "AddEmployee"method="post" action ="php/employeetabsubmit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">      
        <input type="text" name="surname" id = "surname" placeholder="Surname Here">
        <select name="empStanding">
          <option value="ADMIN">ADMIN</option>
          <option value="EMPLOYEE">EMPLOYEE</option>
          <option value="SUPERVISOR">SUPERVISOR</option>

        </select> 
         <button class="add" type="submit" name="add">Add</button>
   </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the button outside the select tag, and it should be working - Everything else looks correct

Comment: My bad, edited my mistake in snipping sample codes. The actual code in my case returns an error in "Undefined index: empStanding" when I post the data using the submit button